# add more form element logic with radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote some code where a user can click `add more` to duplicate all form elements and add values. It's working fine except for radio inputs. I am stuck. How can I solve my problem in an easy way? Below is my code.

```
<div id="dup">
    <p>
        Athlete Name:<br>
        <select name="athlete_name" id="athlete_name[]">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a user</option>
            <option value="2">Candice Falzon</option>
            <option value="5">Athlete Example</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p>
        Sex: 
        <input type="radio" name="athlete_sex" value="Male">Male 
        <input type="radio" name="athlete_sex" value="Female">Female
    </p>
</div>
```

I can not take `athlete_sex` as an array .

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes jQuery can be a stickler about closing tags. I fixed them and now it works:

```js
    var clone = $('#dup:last').clone();

    window.addAnother = function() {
      clone.find('input').attr('name', 'athlete_sex' + ($('#wrapper').children().length + 1));
      $('#wrapper').append(clone);
      clone = clone.clone();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="dup">
    <p>Athlete Name:
      <br />
      <select name="athlete_name" id="athlete_name[]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a user</option>
        <option value="2">Candice Falzon</option>
        <option value="5">Athlete Example</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <p>Sex:
      <input type="radio" name="athlete_sex" value="Male" />Male
      <input type="radio" name="athlete_sex" value="Female" />Female</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addAnother()">Add Another</button>
```

Comment: hey see click add another now u can not select sex of new one due to radio name issue that was main problem